# RegEx to match two or more names in a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I am looking for a pattern that will match only if there are two or more names in the string.

I have so far made this:

```
/(?:\w{2,}\s){2,}/g;
```

```js
function test() {
  var pattern = /(?:\w{2,}\s){2,}/g;
  var pse = ps.children;
  var poe = po.children
  var c = pse.length;
  for (i = 0; i < c; i++) {
    poe[i].textContent = ""+pse[i].textContent.match(pattern);
  }
}

test();
```

```css
#ps{background-color:#9CFF1C;}
#po{background-color:#AAFFFF;}
```

```html
<div id="ps">
  <p>Name</p>
  <p>Name Name</p>
  <p>Name Name Name</p>
  <p>Name Name Name  </p>
</div>
<div id="po">
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
</div>
<div id="op"></div>
```

which yields those results. Seems the snippet strips out whitespaces so I can't provide a correct data sample but it would be easy to copy this to another js fidler site.

But I do not want the trailing white space.
How do I define the pattern so that the white space is only matched when between words? Or is the problem elsewhere?

Thanks.

Comment: What you're asking for is a little unclear. You want to explicitly reject trailing whitespace?

Comment: Hm not exactly. I want the name parts to match as 1 match if there are two or more name parts(words). So "meh" would be false and "My name" would be true but "My name " would not.

Comment: I see. Okay, check out my answer below. I *think* it does what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be misunderstanding you, but what about this?

```
// The "^" character marks the start of the string
// The "$" character marks the end
// Wrapping your expression with these prevents leading and trailing whitespace
var regex = /^(\w+ )+\w+$/;

// Accepts:
regex.test('Brian Vaughn');
regex.test('Brian David Vaughn');

// Rejects:
regex.test(' Brian Vaughn');
regex.test('Brian Vaughn ');
regex.test('Brian');
```

Comment: Just for clarity, what would you do if it had to be global?

Comment: What do you mean by global? The regex?

Comment: /^(\w+ )+\w+$/g doesn't seem to do anything different on my end.. maybe I am looking the wrong place. What would /g do?I probably don't understand why /g is not the same as /m (multiline)

Comment: The "g" modifier wouldn't make a difference in this case. It's used when you're searching for something that may have multiple matches and you want to find them all. In this case, you either have a match or you don't.